# Promise returns Promise.reject how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, promise

How would you catch the returned **Promise.reject()** in the following code snippet?

*I am aware that it is bad practice and the code should be --> reject(delay).*

```
function job(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(delay === 1500) {
            return Promise.reject("This is rejected")
        }
        resolve(delay);
    });
}

function example(){
    job(1500).then((res) => {
        console.log("Resolved -> " + res);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log("Reject -> " + e);
    })
}
example();
```

Comment: You don't. The return value of a promise constructor executor function is ignored, and the constructed promise only rejects if the executor synchronously throws.

Comment: If you already know what's wrong  (`Promise.reject()` instead of only `reject()`) why are you doing it anyway?

Comment: just for curiosity, because it shows in the console -> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is there any resource that you could provide related to your comment? I might be able to accept your response.

Comment: The promise returned from `job` and `promise.reject` are two different things. The `catch` only can handle rejections from the original promise. So it can't be done th way you are doing now

Comment: @derpirscher could you provide the right way?

Comment: @IonKat As you use it in the wrong way, there's no "*right*" way to catch it, as it's **technically impossible**.

Comment: @FZs thank you. I just wonder why my question is downvoted as other people might end up having the same question. Shouldn't we think out of the box?

Comment: @IonKat I think it's because you were asking for something that cannot be done, for no good reason. And as there seems to be no use case of this (preferring to return a rejected promise over calling `reject` or throwing an exception), your question can be seen as unnecessary niggling. However, I don't think that thinking outside of the box is generally bad...

Comment: @IonKat The right (and only) way is to call `reject()` instead of `Promise.reject()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use only the reject function not `Promise.reject`:

```js
function job(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(delay === 1500) {
           reject("This is rejected")
        }
        resolve(delay);
    });
}

function example(){
    job(1500).then((res) => {
        console.log("Resolved -> " + res);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log("Reject -> " + e);
    })
}
example();
```

Comment: You do not need to use return on the rejected

Comment: Yep, I missed to delete it, right.

Comment: @IonKat yes, the `return` might not be needed in this simple example. But the code after `reject(...)` is executed nonetheless. So if you have some code, which should not be executed in the case of a reject, you will also need the `return` to prevent any unwanted sideeffects. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yLh0o7tc/

Comment: That’s the correct way in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to it like this but use *throw* instead.

```js
function job(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (delay === 1500) {
      throw "This is rejected";
    }
    resolve(delay);
  });
}

function example() {
  job(1500).then((res) => {
    console.log("Resolved -> " + res);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log("Reject -> " + e);
  })
}

example();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wan't to reject the promise in the `job` function with a Promise which is already rejected you can simply pass that new Promise to the `reject` parameter no need of the return keyword

```js
function job(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(delay === 1500) {
            reject(Promise.reject("This is rejected"));
        }
        resolve(delay);
    });
}

function example(){
    job(1500).then((res) => {
        console.log("Resolved -> " + res);
    })
    .catch(e => e)
    .catch(e => {
          console.log("Reject -> " + e);
    });
}
example();
```

As Explain at [Promise.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

> The Promise.reject() method returns a Promise object that is rejected with a given reason.

So the `e` parameter pass to the callback passed to the `catch` method will be a promise which is rejected and to get the `reason` you have to attach a `catch` call otherwise you'll get a

> uncaught exception: This is rejected

You have to chain two call to `catch` like in the previous code